# strlen not working correctly

Tags: php, forms, strlen

I'm creating a simple registration form
and my problem is that when I use `strlen` function it's not working true
when I enter number as password it does not show anything
and when I enter not number it shows the message even if it's more than 6 characters

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
     $fname = $_POST['fname'];
     $lname = $_POST['lname'];
     $phone = $_POST['phone-number'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
 }
 if (isset($password)) {
     if (strlen($password < 6)) {
         $password_err = "password must be at least 6 characters";
     }
 }

 ?>
 <?php
 if (isset($password_err)){
 echo $password_err;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `strlen` is not multibyte save. So any character like `ö` will throw the result of. use `mb_strlen()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You are using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) in a bad way. You should use `strlen($variable)` and then the comparison you want (in your case, `< 6`)

So the line on your code should be this:

```
if (strlen($password) < 6) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 if (isset($password)) {
     if (strlen($password) < 6) {
         $password_err = "password must be at least 6 characters";
     }
 }
```

Just a misplacement of close bracket

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (strlen($password < 6)) {
```

To

```
if (strlen($password) < 6) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a small mistake in the use of the strlen method. The position of one of the brackets is wrong. Change the if statement with the strlen to this:

```
if (strlen($password) < 6) {
     $password_err = "password must be at least 6 characters";
 }
```

There should be a closing bracket right after $password.

Answer (score 1):

Strlen is being used in the wrong way. You have it like this:

```
if (strlen($password < 6)) {
```

When you want to use it like this:

```
if (strlen($password) < 6)) {
```

Here is a brief explaination of why it would be like that:

```
$length = strlen($password); // Will output a number so if password is 'password', it will output '8'.

// So lets add that strlen to the if statement
if ($length < 6) { // This will compare that number that $length output, to 6.
    # Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the expression:

```
strlen($password < 6)
```

It should be:

```
strlen($password) < 6
```

#### What is the value of `strlen($password < 6)`?

No matter what is the value of `$password`, the value of the expression `$password < 6` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (a [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)).

[`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) expects a string as argument. You pass it a boolean. It first converts the argument to string then counts its characters.

**How is a boolean converted to a string?**

It's easy to find out:

```
var_dump((string)TRUE)
# string(1) "1"
var_dump((string)FALSE)
# string(0) ""
```

`true` is converted to `'1'`, `false` is converted to `''` (the empty string).

Accordingly, [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns either `1` or `0`.

Answer (score -1):

I was using PHP 7.4 and the OP's method worked.
However, after upgrading to PHP 8, it stopped working.

To make it even more confusing, in PHPStorm, it shows as 'string' after strlen(

So you think that because it shows the little expected data format precursor, that it's going to be ok.